# How to handle static files relative paths in web APIs?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, static-files

My Angular project is running on a different port than my API backend (asp.net). I am using a proxy to route all http requests to the backend webserver as shown below.

```
{
  "/api": {
     "target":  {
       "host": "localhost",
       "protocol": "https:",
       "port": 5001
     },
     "secure": false,
     "logLevel" : "debug",
     "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

my Angular project serve options are,

```
 "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "art-ng-core:build",
            "host": "www.artngcore.com",
            "port": 8500,
            "sslKey": "key.key",
            "sslCert": "server.crt"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "art-ng-core:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
```

My issue here is static files served by the API i.e. Images.

```
<img src={{imagePath}}>
```

My backend static files are served in a different static folder "*SystemData*" with a shared path "*Data*".

Say I have this file with a relative path: `/Data/UserData/test.jpg`. if I provide `src` attribute with a relative path, the URL of the image will look like `https://www.artngcore.com:8500/Data/UserData/test.jpg` where it should be `https://localhost:5001/Data/UserData/test.jpg`

**How can I proxy the call for static files the same way I did for Http calls?**

for now, I worked around it by making my api to provide a full URL instead of relative paths but I am not sure if this is a common or good practice when it comes to handle static files.

I am saving relative paths in my database and I run the following method to generate the URL

```
public string GenerateUrl(string filePath, HttpRequest ctx) {
    string physicalPath = this.GetRootPath() + filePath;
    var url = physicalPath.Replace(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory (),$@"{ctx.Scheme}://{ctx.Host}").Replace(@"SystemData", @"Data");
    return url;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I get what the problem is. Why don't you simply add a section similar to the "/api" section of the proxy config, but with "/Data" instead?

Comment: @JBNizet for static files?

Comment: Your browser doesn't know or care whether what it gets when sending a request to a given URL comes from a static file, a database, or anything else: it send a HTTP request, and gets back an HTTP response.

Comment: @JBNizet, allow me to rephrase, the relative path for Angular webserver is different than the backend API one

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. As I understand your question, you have files served by your backend server at URLs /Data/blablabla, and you want these files to be served by ng serve at URLs /Data/blablabla. So you want ng serve to act as a proxy for those URLs, the same way it acts as a proxy for URLs /api/blablabla.

Comment: Yes correct, since I cant run both webservers on the same port

Comment: So, if that's what you want, do the exact same thing you did for "/api".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do with URLs starting with `"/Data"` the exact same thing you did for URLs starting with `"/api"`.

So... just do the same thing, and add a section in your proxy configuration dor `"/Data"`.